# Find me 5 special squares

Tags: mathematics

Assumption: There are many squares that cannot be written as a number divided by the number of prime factors of that number.

Can you give me $5$ of such squares that are relatively prime?

(Example: $16 = 4^2$ is not such a square since $96 = 4^2\times 6$ has $6$ prime factors)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of all squares that cannot be reached by dividing some number by that number's prime factor count, these are the five smallest that are all relatively prime, I think:

> **16,384,
>
>  4,782,969,
>
>  6,103,515,625,
>
>  678,223,072,849,
>
>  379,749,833,583,241.**
>  (I left 0 and 1 out, because they are borderline cases.)

It looks like

> any square that has exactly 14 prime factors will do.

Since we want relatively prime squares, we'll pick

> $P^{14}$, where $P$ is some prime.

It's definitely a square:

> $P^{14}=(P^7)^2$

and we can rule out the numbers that could be divided to get it:

> 15 prime factors: won't work, $P^{14}\times 15$ has 16 prime factors
>  16 prime factors: won't work, $P^{14}\times 16$ has 18 prime factors
>  17 prime factors: won't work, $P^{14}\times 17$ has 15 prime factors
>  18 prime factors: ... has 17
>  19 prime factors: ... has 15
>  20 prime factors: ... has 17
>  21 prime factors: ... has 16
>  ...
>  24 prime factors: ... has 18
>  ...
>  32 prime factors: ... has 19

And so on, and so on, the number of required factors keeps growing ever further out of reach. The above list includes the 24 and 32 because they have a lot of factors, and I wanted to show how even they don't come close.

And of course the first spoiler block was added as an afterthought, since it seemed funny to write such large numbers. Naturally they are just

> the 14th powers of the five smallest primes.

So, why 14?

> The number of prime factors in a square is always even. We also need a number
>  of prime factors that isn't one smaller than a prime, because otherwise
>  adding just one more factor would make a number that could be divided to get
>  the square.
>
>  So, trying numbers that are one smaller than a composite odd number, 8 doesn't
>  work because 10 has 2 factors, which leaves 14 as the next candidate. Checking 20 and
>  24 would have been next, if 14 hadn't worked.